# symfony2 error: sessionHandler::read()

Tags: php, symfony

i got this error in production server. everything is ok on local server.

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception ErrorException: 
Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(C:/Inetpub/vhosts//tanur.ir/vhosts/tanur.ir/private/session\sess_3olhvc8osdevomrh72bhsra4k6, O_RDWR) 
failed: No such file or directory (2) in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\tanur.ir\httpdocs\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Proxy\SessionHandlerProxy.php line 69" 
at C:\Inetpub\vhosts\tanur.ir\httpdocs\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Proxy\SessionHandlerProxy.php line 69 [] []
```

php version is 5.4.16 on production server

Comment: Have you installed vendors on your production server?

Comment: i didnt becouse its a shared host and i have limited privilages so i uploaded the vendor to production, i usually do the same for my other sites and never enconterd such problems before.

Comment: You may want to check out http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html specifically the part about permissions for the files then, and also verify that the file its looking for actually got uploaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am running Fedora 18 with PHP 5.4 (using php-fpm) + nginx and I faced similar problem. Symfony was complaining that it was unable to create a session file called /var/lib/php/session/sess_

I gave apache rwx permission to /var/lib/php/session using the following acl command and it solved the problem:

```
sudo setfacl -m apache_username:rwx /var/lib/php/session
```

**apache_username** is either apache, www-data depending on your linux distribution, it can be also a custom user

Comment: If I got everything at the comments below the question right, the author has no privileges to make changes at 'his' server, because he works with a shared hosting solution.

Comment: @ztirom Yes you are right. This will work if the user has root access.

Comment: Or `sudo setfacl -m apache /var/lib/php/5.5/session`, if you're on PHP 5.5.

Comment: In Debian/Ubuntu `$ sudo setfacl -m www-data:rwx /var/lib/php/sessions`

Answer (score 6):

just have to add/change these 2 lines in app/config/config.yml to fix it:

```
framework:
session:
    handler_id: session.handler.native_file
    save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/sessions"
```

Answer (score -1):

i think when it comes to symfony deployment errors, in most cases the problem is permissions.

in this case i changed permission of the folder in witch sessions were being saved and now everything works fine.

Comment: "I said the magic word and now it's all fixed." BTW, When leaving an answer, it would be helpful to share what you set the permissions to ;)